# How to send dynamic data to custom email template from controller action?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I need to pass Customer Full Name and Order # dynamically to mail, but not receiving in actual Email.

**Controller**

```
$templateId = 17;
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);

$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate();

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName($customer->getId());

$email_template_variables = array(
   'customer_name' => $fullName,
   'order_id' => $orderID
);

$mail->setTemplateParam($email_template_variables);
$mail->setToEmail($customer->getEmail());
$mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
$mail->setSubject($mailSubject);
$mail->setFromEmail($from_email);
$mail->setFromName($from_name);
$mail->setType('Html');

try {
    $mail->send();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
}
```

Accessing those variables by

```
{{var customer_name}} and {{var order_id}}
```

It is empty. No Value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the variable to that template so that you can get the value in email template. Try the below code

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName($customer->getId());

$email_template_variables = array(
   'customer_name' => $fullName,
   'order_id' => $orderID
);

$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);
```

Answer (score 3):

no need to use `core/email` you can do with `core/email_template`

here i can suggest you to use like this

```
 $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($this->_email_template); 

$vars = array('customer_name' => $fullName,
              'order_id' => $orderID);

 $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);
 $from = $this->getFromMail($this->_identity);
 $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($from['email']);
 $emailTemplate->setSenderName($from['name']);
 $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
 $success_flag = $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $billingAddress->getFirstname(), $vars);
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to changes in template id  and add varibles

Go to **System->transnational email**  and open your template whose id is 17 as you defined in your controller   and add these below variable where you want to show in your mail template.

```
$email_template_variables = array(
       'customer_name' => $fullName,
       'order_id' => $orderID
 )
```

`{{var customer_name}}`   and  `{{var order_id}}`